# Hashmap get returns null

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two Hashmaps

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> inventoryRequirements = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> inventory = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

I have a loop that checks current and adds to it:

```
for(Item item : items){
    int currentRequirement = 0;
    currentRequirement = inventoryRequirements.get(item.get_id());
    inventoryRequirements.put(item.get_id(), currentRequirement++);         
}
```

I have another loop that checks inventory and adds to it:

```
for(Item item : items){
    int currentInventory = 0;
    // this next line returns null
    currentInventory = inventory.get(item.get_id());
    inventory.put(item.get_id(), currentInventory++);           
}
```

The first one works fine, but the second one pukes and returns a null.  I don't understand why the second one does not work.  Both are initially in the same state as depicted in the code sample.

**EDIT**

The two HM get populated as you see here - really! I know it may be hard to believe but the first one works and the second one does not.

Comment: Did you ever `put` anything into `inventory`? Also, why not use `Map<Item, Integer>`s?

Comment: If `inventoryRequirements` starts out empty, the first loop will also fail.

Comment: It never gets to the line to put anything into it.  As to why not Map instead - I have no good answer for that - is there a real advantage?

Comment: Any call to `get(int)` on an empty `HashMap` will return `null`.

Comment: I can assure you the first loop does NOT fail and both get populated the same way.

Comment: On which line it gives null?

Comment: How do you populate them?

Comment: show us the code where you populate them.

Comment: Please practice debugging !! You will get to know the exact solution.. As looking this logically, even in first for loop it should return null.

Comment: @PVR That is what I am doing - DEBUGGING.  And the first loop does work!!!

Comment: What does it returning in that case ??

Comment: I just tried to run your code (modifying the Items list to be a list of Integers). Your first loop throughs NPE. You need to take a closer look at your stack trace and line numbers.

Comment: First loop returns 0 the first time through.  I cannot explain why it works and the other does not.  That's why I posted here.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Because you obviously have other code between your first and second snippet that you aren't showing us.

Comment: Aside from all these don't use `inventory.put(item.get_id(), currentInventory++);` this will eventually put the non-incremented `currentInventroy` value within inventory. Instead use `currentInventory++;inventory.put(item.get_id(), currentInventory);`

Answer (score 14):

Both of the loops you show will throw a `NullPointerException` (NPE) if the key you request via `get()` is not in the `Map`.

`Map.get()` returns `null` when the key is not present (or of course if the value stored with that key is `null`). An `Integer` (autoboxed type) that is `null` can not be autounboxed into an `int` so it throws an NPE.

The safe way of performing this is:

```
for (Item item : items) {
    Integer currentRequirement = inventoryRequirements.get(item.get_id());
    if (currentRequirement != null) {
        inventoryRequirements.put(item.get_id(), currentRequirement++);         
    }
}
```

Of course, it's also completely possible that you have an `Item` in your collection that is `null` and *that* is what is throwing the NPE.

Comment: +1 for your last point, but he does say it's returning null and not throwing null, but that also doesn't make sense since it's an `int`.

Comment: If `get()` returns `null` it throws. Or, his JVM/computer is broken ;) I'm leaning toward an `Item` being `null`, myself.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you have provided is complete, then you haven't put anything in your `hashmap`.
So it will always return `null`.

Comment: True !! But in that case I am wondering that why first piece of code is running fine ???

Comment: That's untrue. The `foreach` loop itself will fail to iterate over the  `HashMap`, if such is a case.

Comment: How come ?? Foreach loop is being iterated on list<Items>.. I dint get you why it would fail..

Comment: @PVR What he means is the code inside the foreach will fail because of what Brian is saying in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a item from `inventory` but it's empty

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to write the code in the following manner:

```
for(Item item : items){
int currentRequirement = 0;
currentRequirement = inventoryRequirements.get(item.get_id());
if(currentRequirement!=null){
//update currentRequirement only if it exists in the map.
   inventoryRequirements.put(item.get_id(), currentRequirement++); 
} else {
   //add it to the map otherwise.
   inventoryRequirements.put(item.get_id(), 1);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugg. Also, when all else fails, don't overlook the possibility that it is not returning null because its not finding the key.  It could be returning null because when the key/value pair was added... the value added was null.  Just spent more time than I care to admit tracking this down.

So, to recap, there are at least two reasons the HashMap could be returning null:

- It's not finding the key
- It is finding the key, but the value inserted for the key is null

Doh!